# Add-on migration from Web Store to G-Suite Marketplace

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-apps-marketplace, google-apps-script-addon

I published a Sheets add-on several years ago. The developer dashboard now says "Publishing Drive Add-ons through Chrome Web Store is no longer supported. Please use the G Suite Marketplace."

Unfortunately, it looks like [this page's](https://developers.google.com/gsuite/add-ons/how-tos/editor-publish-overview) link to [Chrome Web Store migration](https://developers.google.com/gsuite/add-ons/how-tos/gsuite/add-ons/how-tos/cws-migration) instructions is incorrect. Can anyone point me to instructions on moving my add-on from the Chrome Web Store to the G-Suite Marketplace?

**Update**: I found [this page](https://developers.google.com/gsuite/add-ons/how-tos/cws-migration), but it doesn't really offer any info on migrating.

Comment: Would this link be helpful for your situation [How to upgrade Add-ons](https://developers.google.com/gsuite/add-ons/how-tos/upgrade-addons)?

Comment: @Raserhin, that doesn't seem to be it exactly, but thank you. I hadn't seen that page before. If I don't get any migration info in the next few days, I guess I'll just make a copy of the project and re-publish it.

Comment: Why do you think that the migrations instructions are incorrect?